# Indexing in multl-dimentional numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Thank you for your help in advance!

I have a 4D numpy array a

```
a = np.random.random_integers(1,5,(2,3,3,4))
>>> a
array([[[[5, 2, 5, 3],
         [1, 3, 1, 2],
         [4, 3, 1, 2]],

        [[3, 1, 3, 5],
         [2, 5, 2, 3],
         [1, 4, 1, 3]],

        [[4, 2, 4, 3],
         [1, 3, 5, 2],
         [3, 5, 4, 4]]],


       [[[1, 1, 2, 3],
         [2, 1, 5, 3],
         [1, 5, 5, 4]],

        [[1, 2, 3, 3],
         [5, 2, 4, 3],
         [4, 3, 4, 5]],

        [[4, 3, 5, 3],
         [3, 5, 2, 4],
         [4, 3, 3, 1]]]])
```

I have a 3D numpy array b which is the same shape as the last three dimensions of a, and consists of 0 and 1.

```
b = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(3,3,4))
>>> b
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0]]])
```

For each (3, 3, 4) array in a, I want to select elements which has a value of 1 in the same location in array b, and update these values in a according to a another array c which has the shape of the first dimension of a:

```
c = np.array([-1, -2])
```

So that value in a[0,:] which has value of 1 in array b would become -1 (c[0])

and values in a[1,:]. which has value of 1 in array b would become -2 (c[1])

Ultimately I want to get an array with the same shape as a with updated values in an efficient way

```
>>> return 
array([[[[5, 2, 5, 3],
         [1, 3, 1, -1],
         [-1, 3, -1, 2]],

        [[3, -1, -1, 5],
         [-1, -1, 2, -1],
         [-1, -1, 1, -1]],

        [[4, 2, 4, -1],
         [1, -1, -1, 2],
         [-1, 5, -1, 4]]],


       [[[1, 1, 2, 3],
         [2, 1, 5, -2],
         [-2, 5, -2, 4]],

        [[1, -2, -2, 3],
         [-2, -2, 4, -2],
         [-2, -2, 4, -2]],

        [[4, 3, 5, -2],
         [3, -2, -2, 4],
         [-2, 3, -2, 1]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasting and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
tmp = b[None] * c[:,None,None,None]
out = np.where(tmp, tmp, a)
```

Or (credit to @Chrysophylaxs):

```
out = np.where(b, c[:, None, None, None], a)
```

Or, to assign to `a`:

```
tmp = b[None] * c[:,None,None,None]
m = tmp!=0
a[m] = tmp[m]
```

Output:

```
array([[[[ 5,  2,  5,  3],
         [ 1,  3,  1, -1],
         [-1,  3, -1,  2]],

        [[ 3, -1, -1,  5],
         [-1, -1,  2, -1],
         [-1, -1,  1, -1]],

        [[ 4,  2,  4, -1],
         [ 1, -1, -1,  2],
         [-1,  5, -1,  4]]],


       [[[ 1,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 2,  1,  5, -2],
         [-2,  5, -2,  4]],

        [[ 1, -2, -2,  3],
         [-2, -2,  4, -2],
         [-2, -2,  4, -2]],

        [[ 4,  3,  5, -2],
         [ 3, -2, -2,  4],
         [-2,  3, -2,  1]]]])
```

Comment: `np.where(b, c[:, None, None, None], a)` :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs nice one ;)

Answer (score 0):

In straightforward way:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i][np.where(b)] = c[i]

print(a)
```

---

```
[[[[ 5  2  5  3]
   [ 1  3  1 -1]
   [-1  3 -1  2]]

  [[ 3 -1 -1  5]
   [-1 -1  2 -1]
   [-1 -1  1 -1]]

  [[ 4  2  4 -1]
   [ 1 -1 -1  2]
   [-1  5 -1  4]]]


 [[[ 1  1  2  3]
   [ 2  1  5 -2]
   [-2  5 -2  4]]

  [[ 1 -2 -2  3]
   [-2 -2  4 -2]
   [-2 -2  4 -2]]

  [[ 4  3  5 -2]
   [ 3 -2 -2  4]
   [-2  3 -2  1]]]]
```